# React Router <Link> and <Route> not passing state to Component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

React Router: Link and Route not passing state to Component

I’m building an online shopping app with React, Redux, and React Router. On the home page, all items are displayed. I want users to be able to click on an image and be taken to a page with item details for that item.

Here's how I’m trying to do that:

- In App.js, I’m using BrowserRouter, Route, and Switch for routing
- In Home.js, I’m using react-router's Link to link an image on the Home page to an item details page; the Link is supposed to pass the ID to the Item component as state (see the Home.js code below)
- Item.js is supposed to render an items detail page. The ID of the item will be passed to the Item component, which will render the details for that item.

This seems simple, and I’ve seen a lot of discussion about this on SO and across the web. Here are some that I have already tried:

[Display item details after clicking Link in React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820210/display-item-details-after-clicking-link-in-react-router)

[React router how to click thru to detail components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611653/react-router-how-to-click-thru-to-detail-components)

[Passing values through React-Router v4 <Link />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598854/passing-values-through-react-router-v4-link)

[Tyler McGinnis - Pass props to React Router's Link component](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-link/)

[Medium - How to pass props to React routes components](https://medium.com/alturasoluciones/how-to-pass-props-to-routes-components-29f5443eee94)

I’m able to get the URL to change to correspond to the item’s ID, but I can’t get the Item component to render with the right information, and sometimes I get errors depending on the method I’m using. I hard coded the words "Item Component" inside a div in Item.js, and that will render when I click on the images from the Home page. Otherwise, nothing will render *or* I receive the two following TypeErrors:

**App.js:**

```
<Route path="/products" render={(props) => (<Item {...props} id={this.props.location.id} />) }/>

export default withRouter(App);
```

`<App />` is wrapped in `<BrowserRouter>` in index.js.

I receive the following error when clicking on an image from the home page:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**

When the above “render” code is removed from  and replaced with “component={ Item }”, I receive this error from Item.js:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined**

---

Here are my other code snippets:

**Item.js:**

```
class Item extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            item: this.props.location.state
        }
    }

    render() {
        let item = this.state.item;
        return (
            <div className="item" key={item.id}>
                <div className="item-image">
                    <img src={item.img} alt={item.title} />
                </div>
                <div className="card-component">
                    <span className="item-title">{item.title}</span>
                    <p className="item-price"><b>${item.price}</b></p>
                    <p className="item-desc">{item.desc}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

---

**Home.js** (where all items are displayed), the item details page is linked like so:

```
<Link to = 
    {{ pathname: `/products/${item.category}`,
    search: `?id=${item.id}`,
    state: {id: `${item.id}`} }}
    component={ Item }>
    <img src={item.img} alt={item.title} />
</Link>
```

**UPDATE**

I have wrapped the `<Item/>` component in `withRouter()`.
In Item.js, if I set the state in the constructor as `{ item: this.props.location.state }`, nothing renders as it should (only a dollar sign is on the screen, since the price section contains a hard coded dollar sign).

I tried setting the Item.js state to `null` in the constructor, then calling `this.setState` with  `{ item: this.props.location.state }` in `componentDidMount()`. When I do this, I receive the following error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'img' of null**

Also, if I leave the `render={(props) => (<Item {...props} id={this.props.location.id} />) }` in the `<Route>` in `App.js`, I receive this error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**

If I change `<Route>` back to `component={ Item }`, and the Item.js constructor state is set to `{ item: this.props.location.state }`, just the dollar sign renders.

**UPDATE**: include App.js and Routes.js code

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  withRouter,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer';
import { Routes } from './constants/Routes';


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            { Routes }
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

**Routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../components/Home';
import Item from '../components/shopping/Item';
import Cart from '../components/cart/Cart';
import OrderStatus from '../components/footer/OrderStatus';
import GiftCards from '../components/footer/GiftCards';
import ReturnsExchanges from '../components/footer/Returns-Exchanges';
import Contact from '../components/footer/Contact';

export const Routes = <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={ Home } />
            <Route path="/products" component={ Item }/>
            <Route path="/cart" component={ Cart } />
            <Route path="/order-status" component={ OrderStatus } />
            <Route path="/gift-cards" component={ GiftCards } />
            <Route path="/returns-exchanges" component={ ReturnsExchanges } />
            <Route path="/contact" component={ Contact } />
            </div>
```

Comment: Hi, Have you wrapped your `App` component with `withRouter`?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I just tried that, but I am now getting a new error. I will update my original post.

Comment: The new error seems to be related to `BrowserRouter`. Checkout my answer below. Hope it helps. Also, will be helpful to see your `App.js` code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just saw your edit about the `App.js` code. I will edit my question and include it at the bottom.

Comment: I found this to be a very well-written question, I wish everyone would be as detailed as you when posting @Jenna

Comment: @Filtenborg Thank you! I tried to follow the guidelines. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to access `history` objects properties in any component, you need to wrap that component with `withRouter`.
import `withRouter` from `react-router-dom` and wrap your `App` component like this:

```
export default withRouter(App);
```

More on [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md).

Also, in `index.js`, make sure your `<App />` is wrapped inside `<BrowserRouter>`.

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
   <BrowserRouter>
     <App />
   </BrowserRouter>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**EDIT:**

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**

Replace your `constructor` with the following code. When implementing a constructor for React Component `super(props)` should be before any other statement otherwise props will be `undefined` in constructor.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        item: this.props.location.state
    }
}
```

**Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'img' of null**

Reason: 
Initial value of the state should not be `null`. You may pass empty object `{}` but not null, in this case.
You're trying to access `img`, `title`, `price` and `desc` in `Item.js` but only passing `id` in `state` of `<Link>` in `Home.js`.

```
<Link to = 
    {{ pathname: `/products/${item.category}`,
       search: `?id=${item.id}`,
       state: {id: `${item.id}`} //pass img, title, desc, price etc as well
    }}
    component={ Item }>
    <img src={item.img} alt={item.title} />
</Link>
```

Comment: I just changed my index.js to wrap the `<App />` component inside `<BrowserRouter>`, so that error is taken care of. But I am now getting an error when I click on one of the item images and am directed to the item details page. I will edit my original question.

Comment: Try wrapping your ‘Item’ component with withRouter. The thing is, you have to wrap any component that needs to access this.props.location.

Comment: I have done this, and will update my question. Thank you again for the help. It might not seem like it, but I might be making some progress...?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have edited my answer with attempts to resolve the recent errors. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, and your time spent on this. I had a bad case of tunnel vision and was solely focused on that ID number. I also learned a bit more about the functionality of `withRouter()`, so thank you for that additionally!

Comment: withRouter link is broken